# Is it possible to see MPI_ISEND not to return immediately

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

I realised recently that during the first iterations of my simulation, I experienced particularly slower steps which boiled down to the following section

```
 do I= 1, hpc_nodes 
     call mpi_isend(cnt(i), 1, mpi_integer, whoisrootInNode(i), 10000, comm, req(i), mpierr) 
 enddo
```

I realised that one of the ith  `mpi_isend` returns after around 2 seconds, while the rest would be a fraction of second. This eventually fades off and  all mpi_isend calls will be minimal in cost. However, I am trying to understand why this could happen.

Why is it that sometimes mpi_isend would return after 2 seconds for a certain `I` within the same rank and the one right  after `I+1` is 10 times faster - why does it only happen in the beginning , i.e. the code section is within a big time loop and after 2-3 time steps this problem seems to vanish

Is this something related to the following [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.03271.pdf)

Comment: this looks like an implementation issue. can you share a [mcve] and state which `Open MPI` version and interconnect you are using?

Comment: I just tried to make a smaller program example, unfortunately, it did not show the issue. We use openmpi 4.1.0 with ucx the most recent one (the recently released package)

Comment: Did you scim the article, `(...)The cost of blocking/unblocking tasks is sometimes not negligible. Typically, the pause operation of a task produces a context switch, requires the runtime system to keep alive the stack of the paused task (e.g., 8 MB of stack size) and increases the scheduling overhead.(...)`  Is this still relevant today @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: context switch is several orders of magnitude faster than 2s. I'd rather think `MPI_Isend()` tries an eager send that internally blocks waiting for resources. But this is just a guess given I did not witness that on a reproducer.

Comment: Do you have any hints on how I could debug this using my actual production code? So far, I am simply timing the `mpi_isend` which takes around 2s in the first 2-3 iterations - It is certainly also strange why the time it takes to return a `mpi_isend` is not consistent given I got exactly same inputs to the API

Comment: my best bet would be to extract a reproducer and ask it on Open MPI github or mailing list

Comment: Is it just the first mpi_isend in a given run that takes a long time? Or is it a later one, or a number of them? How big is hpc_nodes?

Comment: Is this a scatter or an alltoall or similar? Can you use the collective, maybe in the non-blocking version?

Comment: hpc_nodes goes is from 4 to 20. It is ALWAYS  the first mpi_isend among the hpc_nodes loop.

Comment: Sounds as though it is setting up something which is reused on subsequent calls. I agree with Gilles, extract a minimal example and ask the OpenMPI guys directly - though at your end it might be worth looking into whether you can do this with collectives or mpi_sendrecv and so avoid non-blocking all together, depends on more details than you have provided already. Another thought - Is it possible to make sure the corresponding receive is posted well in advance?

Comment: Thanks @IanBush. The receive is posted in advance, but I could make them more in advance - I will try this . I wish I can make a reproducer but have failed sofar. I simply tried to mimic the loop with mpi_isend  with sending a number across on  a single file program, but this does not show the problem